# Apache CustomLog automation?

Tags: apache-2.2

I would like to log images to a seperate file on the server for all domains.

This works:

```
CustomLog logs/host1-access-log combined env=!image  
CustomLog logs/image-access-log combined env=image
```

But it is necessary to add this to each and every vhost. This quickly becomes a problem when you have 24710 hosts.

I don't have them :) but is it possible to get by with a single Customlog directive since all images are logged in the same file?

I'm using Apache 2.2.2, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the [CustomLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) directives into your main Apache httpd configuration (main scope) instead of in every `<VirtualHost>` container if you really want to log all image access log entries into one file.